# OrientDB select unique Vertices from multiple Edges

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases

I have 2 vertices User and Stamp. Vertices are related by three edges Have, WishToHave and Selling.

I'm wish to select unique Stamps that have any relation with User. To do it I was running this command:

```
select expand(out('Have', 'WishToHave', 'Selling')) from #12:0
```

The problem with this command is that it returns 'Stamp1' few times, because it has Have and Selling edges.

How can I select all unique/distinct Stamps related to User1?

To init test data for this example:

```
create class User extends V
create class Stamp extends V

create class Have extends E
create class WishToHave extends E
create class Selling extends E

create vertex User set name = 'User1'
create vertex Stamp set name = 'Stamp1'
create vertex Stamp set name = 'Stamp2'
create vertex Stamp set name = 'Stamp3'


create edge Have from (select from User where name = 'User1') to (select from Stamp where name = 'Stamp1')
create edge WishToHave from (select from User where name = 'User1') to (select from Stamp where name = 'Stamp2')
create edge Selling from (select from User where name = 'User1') to (select from Stamp where name = 'Stamp1')
create edge Selling from (select from User where name = 'User1') to (select from Stamp where name = 'Stamp3')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your case with your structure:

[image]

To retrieve unique vertices you could use the `DISTINCT()` function. I can give you two examples:

**Query 1:** Using `EXPAND()` in the target query

```
SELECT EXPAND(DISTINCT(@rid)) FROM (SELECT EXPAND(out('Have', 'WishToHave', 'Selling')) FROM #12:0)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Query 2:** Using `UNWIND` in the target query

```
SELECT EXPAND(DISTINCT(out)) FROM (SELECT out('Have', 'WishToHave', 'Selling') FROM #12:0 UNWIND out)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi @TWeb, glad to have been helpful.